# Angular 6 upgrade does not execute tests

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular6

I upgraded my app to Angular 6. After all the updates I had to do to the code, my app runs, but the tests don't execute.

I created a new app with `ng new Angular6` and compared the `karma.conf.js`, `package.json`, `test.ts` and `angular.json (fmr angular-cli.json)` below are all my files.

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
     frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
     plugins: [
       require('karma-jasmine'),
       require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
       require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
       require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
       require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
     ],
     client: {
       clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
     },
     coverageIstanbulReporter: {
       dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
       reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
       fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
     },
     reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
     port: 9876,
     colors: true,
     logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
     autoWatch: true,
     browsers: ['Chrome'],
     singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**test.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "awesomy",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "build": "ng build --output-hashing=all --output-path=build/ --prod --source-map",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "lint": "ng lint taxonomy --format stylish --force && ng lint taxonomy-e2e --format stylish --force",
    "e2e": "ng taxonomy-e2e --proxy-config proxy.conf.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.2",
    "@codebakery/origami": "^1.3.0-beta.1",
    "@ibm/plex": "^1.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.3.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "c3": "^0.4.18",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.10.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ngx-uploader": "^4.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-typescript": "^3.0.12",
    "protractor": "5.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.4",
    "ts-node": "3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
...,
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/c3/c3.min.css"
        ],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ],
        "watch": false,
        "codeCoverage": true
      }
    },
...}
```

**Terminal**

```
➜  app git:(awesomy) ✗ npm run test

> awesomy@0.0.0 test /Users/cooluser/Documents/Taxonomy/app
> ng test --watch=false

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active(node:11168) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
21 05 2018 13:28:22.321:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.2 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
21 05 2018 13:28:22.323:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
21 05 2018 13:28:22.332:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
21 05 2018 13:28:36.462:INFO [Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4)]: 
Connected on socket 3iFHNxYaUOZZcufcAAAA with id 89513560
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.003 secs / 0 secs)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! taxonomy@0.0.0 test: `ng test --watch=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the taxonomy@0.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cooluser/.npm/_logs/2018-05-21T17_28_37_632Z-debug.log
```

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: Have you looked into /Users/cooluser/.npm/_logs/2018-05-21T17_28_37_632Z-debug.log for more details?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @JanneHarju I did not. I just created a new app and transferred the directories where they belonged.